# Why importing Numpy creates many processes

Tags: python, numpy

I got no proper answer after looking up for some time. I am using a processor with 4 cores; Linux, python 2.7.
While importing Numpy, I see 4 processes are created. Although only one of them is doing all the work, which is in fact the process with pid same as when I do os.getpid() from the python script. Why the other 3 are created? Is there any way to prevent from spawning? For a quick test, I did this:

```
import numpy as np

raw_input() # just to pause

size = 1000000
a = np.random.randn(size)
b = np.random.randn(size)

while(True):
    c = a * b
```

Comment: Hi, how did you witness that numpy specifically creates 4 processes? Did you use htop or pstree to verify this?

Comment: Yes.. I checked it in htop.. My main concern is if this creates this many subprocesses, then the number will be multiplied by the number of scripts I run in parallel. For example, if I want to run 10 of these in parallel, 40 processes would be created, unnecessarily filling the processlist. I have already observed this creates 12 processes when 3 of them are executed.

Comment: It's likely your linear algebra lib. Is your numpy using MKL?

Comment: No. It is probably using openblas.

Comment: @TapabrataMukherjee do you have a solution for this?